# Johansen cointegration Test for spread generation

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, algorithmic-trading, cointegration

I'm using the python statsmodels version of the johansen cointegration test and I'm looking for some advice on how best to generate the spread used within a pairs trading algorithm.

For example I've got the following output from the Johansen test of 2 stocks:

```
--------------------------------------------------
--> Trace Statistics
variable statistic Crit-90% Crit-95%  Crit-99%
r = 0    13.7837 13.4294 15.4943 19.9349
r = 1    0.6236 2.7055 3.8415 6.6349
--------------------------------------------------
--> Eigen Statistics
variable statistic Crit-90% Crit-95%  Crit-99%
r = 0    13.16 12.2971 14.2639 18.52
r = 1    0.6236 2.7055 3.8415 6.6349
--------------------------------------------------
eigenvectors:
 [[ 0.04981179  0.00546497]
 [-0.08553954  0.02214011]]
--------------------------------------------------
eigenvalues:
 [0.0510797  0.00248153]
--------------------------------------------------
```

Now I can see that I have some level of cointegration and I understand that the first row of the eigenvectors represents the best estimators for cointegration, but how should I use them in my code. I've previously calculated spread like so (when using beta from an OLS on the two stocks): `stock1 - B * stock2`

However now I've switched to using the Johansen method I believe I'm presented with two estimators to use for each price series but I'm unsure of how to use them.

I'd be grateful for some advice ?